# combine data frames after for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a list. Then I start a for loop, in that for loop I first convert the variable names into strings and then assign the list contend to the strings so that I get the right name with the right content.
After the loop has finished I do want to combine item#1 with #4 from the list, item#2 and #5 ect.
But when combining the items then I get the following:

`Error in [.data.frame(LoopVariable, , "F_corrected_normed_error") : 
  undefined columns selected`

later one when I want to do calculations with `InorganicNoStdCondition`

Here is my code example:

```
ResidualList = list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition = IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition,
                    IAEA_C2_EAstd = IAEA_C2_EAstd,
                    IAEA_C2_STstd = IAEA_C2_STstd,
                    IAEA_C2_Bothstd = IAEA_C2_Bothstd,
                    TIRI_I_NoStdCondition = TIRI_I_NoStdCondition,
                    TIRI_I_EAstd = TIRI_I_EAstd,
                    TIRI_I_STstd = TIRI_I_STstd,
                    TIRI_I_Bothstd = TIRI_I_Bothstd
                    )          

C = 8

for(j in 1:C) {

#convert list Variable to string for later usage in filename as unique identifier!!    

SubNameString = names(ResidualList)[j]
SubNameString = paste0(SubNameString, "Residuals")

#print(SubNameString)
SubNameString = ResidualList[[j]]



SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed"] = round(SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed"] /       mean(SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed"]),
                                              digit = 5
                                              )

SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"] = round(SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"] / mean(SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"]),
                                                    digit = 5
                                                    )
#View(SubNameString[ ,"F_corrected_normed"])
#print(SubNameString)

}
      View(SubNameString)
      InorganicNoStdCondition = data.frame(cbind(IAEA_C2_NoStdConditionResiduals, 
                                                 TIRI_I_NoStdConditionResiduals
                                                 )
                                           )
```

Comment: Please give a reproducible example

Comment: @Johannes It is better to show some data using `dput` ie. dput(ResidualList)` if the output is not that big.  Also, if possible, the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to change the `names` of `ResidualList`, you could do:

```
   names(ResidualList) <- paste0(names(ResidualList), 'Residuals')
```

If you want to use `for` loop

```
for(j in 1:C){
   names(ResidualList)[j] <- paste0(names(ResidualList[j]), 'Residuals')
   ResidualList[[j]][ ,"F_corrected_normed"] <- round(ResidualList[[j]][
      ,"F_corrected_normed"] / mean(ResidualList[[j]][ ,"F_corrected_normed"]),
                                           digit = 5)
   ResidualList[[j]][ ,"F_corrected_normed_error"] <- round(ResidualList[[j]][
    ,"F_corrected_normed_error"] / mean(ResidualList[[j]][
    ,"F_corrected_normed_error"]),digit = 5)                                     
 } 

  names(ResidualList)
  #[1] "IAEA_C2_NoStdConditionResiduals" "IAEA_C2_EAstdResiduals"         
  #[3] "IAEA_C2_STstdResiduals"          "IAEA_C2_BothstdResiduals"       
  #[5] "TIRI_I_NoStdConditionResiduals"  "TIRI_I_EAstdResiduals"          
  #[7] "TIRI_I_STstdResiduals"           "TIRI_I_BothstdResiduals"
```

For combining the list elements 1 with 5, 2 with 6 etc.

```
res <- lapply(1:4, function(i) do.call(`cbind`,ResidualList[c(i, i+4)]))
```

It is not clear how you want the column names to be named in each `list` element of `res`

#### data

```
 set.seed(29)
 IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10),
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 IAEA_C2_EAstd <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 IAEA_C2_STstd <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 IAEA_C2_Bothstd <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 TIRI_I_NoStdCondition <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 TIRI_I_EAstd <-   data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 TIRI_I_STstd <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))
 TIRI_I_Bothstd <- data.frame(F_corrected_normed=rnorm(10), 
     F_corrected_normed_error=runif(10))


     ResidualList <- list(IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition = IAEA_C2_NoStdCondition,
                   IAEA_C2_EAstd = IAEA_C2_EAstd,
                   IAEA_C2_STstd = IAEA_C2_STstd,
                   IAEA_C2_Bothstd = IAEA_C2_Bothstd,
                   TIRI_I_NoStdCondition = TIRI_I_NoStdCondition,
                   TIRI_I_EAstd = TIRI_I_EAstd,
                   TIRI_I_STstd = TIRI_I_STstd,
                   TIRI_I_Bothstd = TIRI_I_Bothstd
                )
```